# How to Upload photo into Foursquare API in Iphone

Tags: iphone, photo, foursquare

I am Working on Foursquare API and it's working fine for log in .

Now i wants to upload photo into Foursquare, i have access token and all the relevant information.

I had searched lot for that but not finding code.Can Anyone please help me ????

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

What type of photo are you trying to upload?

If you're trying to upload a profile photo of the currently auth'd user, check out this endpoint:

https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/users/update

If you want to add a photo to a venue, tip, or check-in, take a look at:

https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/photos/add

Hope this helps!